# Android Facebook single sign-on - multiple key hashes possible?

Tags: android, facebook

We're using Facebook SSO (single sign on) for one of our Android apps. It's working well except that we have 3 developers building the app with debug keys, and then the release key we sign with for the market. Is there any way we can have the facebook SSO work with multiple keys so we can test with our debug keys?

Thanks.

Comment: If you go to developers.facebook.com and to your app's settings > basic settings > mobile and devices > android key hash, you should be able to add multiple keys. Is this not working for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please visit developer.facebook.com/apps and select your app. Now select Settings > Basic. On the bottom you will see How Your App Integrates With Facebook. In the Android Keyhash field, you should be able to copy multiple keys.

Comment: Can i achieve the same result for GOOGLE Sign in also ?? If yes how ?? If no why ??

Thanx