# Facebook API key hash - debug and release

Tags: android, facebook, key

I've integrated Facebook to my App, created a valid hash key and saved the key on facebook.
I used a different key for debug and release. When I released, I had to regenerate the key hash from the release keystore.

Now I cannot log in to facebook using the debug key. Anyone know how I could still use the debug version as well as the release version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just doing this myself, and discovered that this was already answered here: [Android Facebook single sign-on - multiple key hashes possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170544/android-facebook-single-sign-on-multiple-key-hashes-possible).

All you need to do is add (paste) both key hashes into the FB configuration for your app, and you should be all set.

Comment: oh well, I've already created another application for debugging. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Can i achieve the same result for GOOGLE Sign in also ?? If yes how ?? If no why ?? Thanx